# Camera app is missing from my Galaxy Nexus

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-nexus, camera, 4.1-jelly-bean, gallery

I ran bigxie's 4.1 jellybean for a while, worked great, switched to the same brand but 4.1.1 instead (I always do a full wipe) and since then I have issues with my camera. I think the installation of Camera 360 might have done something to cause my regular camera and Gallery app to have problems (both of them simply crash upon start).

I just installed the latest AOKP (4.1.1) and tried two separate gapps, the most popular one from somewhere in april that some forums claim fix this issue, and also the absolutely newest one. Both give me the same issue as the 4.1.1 bigxie ROM.

Is it possible that Camera 360 did this? What can I do to troubleshoot this? When I go to "manage apps" and then "all" I can't even find an app called "Camera", and also nothing called "com.android.camera". Are system apps even included in gapps? Can I find the system app "Camera" from somewhere and just install it to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by **reinstalling** bigxie's 4.1.1 ROM from scratch (with a full wipe). I suspect that fiddling around with TitaniumBackup caused me to remove the system camera app, and for some reason this was not put in when I installed AOKP + gapps.

Please note! Full wipe and complete reinstall of a ROM that is missing the Camera app will not help. Therefore, choose a stock ROM or a ROM close to stock that you know include the Camera system app.

If this does not help, try reseting the phone completely to locked bootloader, unrooted stock ROM and so on as you will probably want to return it anyway if the Camera app is still gone in the stock installation :)